# Autocomplete testing on Azure Search explorer

Tags: autocomplete, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to build and test the auto complete feature on a master item lookup tables using Azure Search (for a ASP MVC application). The search index was done with the suggesterName SG set to ItemDisplayName

I was looking to test it first on Azure portal- so that I could aim to replicate the results via code. This is because the results I am getting in code are quite unexpected

As I type the substring the itemDislayName, the expectation was that upto 5 selected names will be displayed

On the portal, I tried a query string of

search=str&suggesterName=SG

with the base request URL containing the index, api version and sugestorName-but I don't get results of items containing 'str' and with the fuzziness as below

Could you please guide around 
[1] how I can get suggestor output in azure portal-search explorer 
[2] can I control fuzziness using queryType and ~1,~2

I was referring to these 3 links
1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/suggestions
and

2) https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-Search-103-Azure-Search-Suggestions-with-Liam-Cavanagh

3) gunnarpeipman.com/2016/07/azure-search-suggesters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search Portal doesn't support the Suggestion API yet. You will need to use an HTTP client like Fiddler or Postman.

Make sure you use the right URL for you Suggest requests:

`https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[index name]/docs/suggest`

Please use our User Voice page to vote for adding the Suggest API to the Portal: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search